# Is it possible to use が twice in a subordinate clause?

Tags: particle-が, subordinate-clauses

Is it possible to use double が **within the same subordinate clause**, or is it grammatically incorrect/awkward?

For example:

> 私が目が覚めたとき。。。

> 私が腹が立つとき。。。

> 彼が腹が黒いのに。。。

Is there a context in which these may work, or is が+が in one subordinate clause of this kind unnatural to Japanese?

Comment: I think unnaturalness comes from double が regardless of inside one subordinate clause - but 私が目が覚めた時 sounds *possible*.

Answer (score 2):

There might be some tendency to avoid that, but the construction is not too rare either.

[小栗虫太郎『白蟻』](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000125/files/666_47253.html)

> 貴方は、私が雷が嫌いなのをご承知でいらっしゃいましょう。

[海野十三『大脳手術』](https://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000160/files/3048_20671.html)

> それから幾日経ってか、私が気がついたときは、私は一頭のゴリラになり果てていた。